# How to extract the synonym values from an entity in Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I need to extract all the synonym values for a particular entity. For example, I have an entity named `Vehicle` with values `Car` and `Bus`. For `Car` I have three synonyms, `Mercedes`,`Volvo` and `Audi`. Now what I need is when the entity `Vehicle` is detected in the user input for a value `Car`, I want to extract all the three synonym values present for `Car`. I know `@Vehicle.literal` will return the exact synonym value detected in the user input. But how can I retrieve all the synonyms for a particular entity value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Conversation API to [get information on an entity and its metadata](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?#get_entity). That information is not available in a dialog context itself.

IMHO a better way would be to use a database or similar to match up the detected entity with a list of synonyms. Usually, Conversation service is not used on its own, but part of a solution. The app server could perform the lookup if flagged. Take a look at the [dialog actions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions) for that. Or this suggestion on [using the method of replaced markers in an answer](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#replaced-markers).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was using the Watson Conversation with the ServiceNow platform to build a chat-bot capable of performing necessary actions based on user's input. The synonyms for a particular entity value were needed for a keyword based search on a specific table in the ServiceNow tool and retrieve relevant data accordingly. In this case the listSynonyms(params,callback()) method of the Conversation API did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not extract the synonyms.One thing yiu can do is to create another entity with values as your car names and synonyms as vehicle.So that whenever a vehicle is input it will give you all the entity values.